# Make loading circle appear with transition

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transitions

I added a simple loading circle from template. Before `submit` button is clicked it has `style.display = 'none'`, after `submit` clicked, it becomes `style.display = 'inline-block'` and after 3 second it disappears.

It works fine, but I want **this loading circle to appear not abruptly but smoothly**. I tried transition, but it didn't work

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button')
const load = document.querySelector('#load')

load.style.display = 'none'

submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      load.style.display = 'inline-block'

      setTimeout(() => { load.style.display = 'none'}, 3000)
})
```

```css
body {
      background-color: #313038;
      
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
}

.button {
      padding: 10px 13px;
      
      color: white;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: 0.1s;

      border: 1px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;

      cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      transition: 0.1s;
      color: black;
}

.lds-roller {
      display: inline-block;
      transition: display ease 2s;

      transition: 0.5s;

      margin-top: 100px;

      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
}

.lds-roller div {
      animation: lds-roller 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
      transform-origin: 40px 40px;
}

.lds-roller div:after {
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 7px;
      height: 7px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #fff;
      margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(1) {
      animation-delay: -0.036s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(1):after {
      top: 63px;
      left: 63px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: -0.072s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(2):after {
      top: 68px;
      left: 56px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: -0.108s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(3):after {
      top: 71px;
      left: 48px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: -0.144s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(4):after {
      top: 72px;
      left: 40px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(5) {
      animation-delay: -0.18s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(5):after {
      top: 71px;
      left: 32px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(6) {
      animation-delay: -0.216s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(6):after {
      top: 68px;
      left: 24px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(7) {
      animation-delay: -0.252s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(7):after {
      top: 63px;
      left: 17px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(8) {
      animation-delay: -0.288s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(8):after {
      top: 56px;
      left: 12px;
}

@keyframes lds-roller {
      0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src="test.js" defer></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
</head>

<body>
      <button type='submit' class='button' id='submit-button'>Submit</button>


      <div id='load' class="lds-roller">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of changing `display:`, could you use `opacity:`? That can transition from 0 to 1 for a smooth effect.

Comment: well, that sounds logical) will try now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display` can't be animated, so as Michael G recommends you can transition `opacity`. A more extensible way to to so is to add a class to the element and leverage `css` to handle the style updates, especially if you need to do more style additions to the element in the future

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button')
const load = document.querySelector('#load')


submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  load.classList.add("active");
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    load.classList.remove("active");
  }, 3000)
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #313038;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 13px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.1s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.1s;
  color: black;
}

.lds-roller {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.lds-roller.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.lds-roller div {
  animation: lds-roller 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  transform-origin: 40px 40px;
}

.lds-roller div:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.036s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(1):after {
  top: 63px;
  left: 63px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.072s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(2):after {
  top: 68px;
  left: 56px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.108s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(3):after {
  top: 71px;
  left: 48px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -0.144s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(4):after {
  top: 72px;
  left: 40px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -0.18s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(5):after {
  top: 71px;
  left: 32px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -0.216s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(6):after {
  top: 68px;
  left: 24px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -0.252s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(7):after {
  top: 63px;
  left: 17px;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -0.288s;
}

.lds-roller div:nth-child(8):after {
  top: 56px;
  left: 12px;
}

@keyframes lds-roller {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type='submit' class='button' id='submit-button'>Submit</button>


  <div id='load' class="lds-roller">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```